# My identity was hidden. Do you know who I am?

Tags: riddle, video-games

> My true identity was hidden from myself and the world, I am not what I appear.
>   I'm a master of all weapons and fighting styles, I can adapt to any situation.
>   Some worship me, others hate me. I allow legends, myths, and gods to live on.
>   When I awoke, I took full control and grew stronger so that I might protect the world from coming threats.
>   Who I was created to protect I destroyed. I fight to hold the world in balance.
>   Who am I?

a hint to help:

> People aren't taking the first line literally enough, so I'll expand on it a little with another line.
>  My body is a mask, I can change or shed it as I choose.

Comment: Are you the avatar?

Comment: Nice riddle but maybe a little too broad? Can you provide more clues to narrow the possibilities?

Comment: If you think about it, nearly every game protagonist/antagonist could come in this list... It then becomes just a preference...

Comment: @Saeïdryl added a hint that should narrow the possibilities down a bit, but none of the current answers address all parts of the original riddle

Comment: @Dragonrage If so, don't hesitate to tell them which point doesn't work with their answers in comment, maybe they are a bit lost without return from you :)

Comment: @Saeïdryl alright, will do. thanks for the tip

Comment: Are you a specific character? Or are you more of a character archetype or concept?

Comment: @Nzall a specific character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> A Tenno from Warframe

My true identity was hidden from myself and the world, I am not what I appear.

> The player themself does not learn what a Tenno truly is until far into the game, and it is no secret that most of the AI characters in the game do not know either.

> "What flesh lies within that Warframe?" -General Sargas Ruk

I'm a master of all weapons and fighting styles, I can adapt to any situation.

> A key concept of the game is leveling and "mastering" as many different gear pieces (weapons) as possible

Some worship me, others hate me. I allow legends, myths, and gods to live on.

> The Arbiters of Hexis and the colony of Baro Ki'Teer all regarded the Tenno as almost divine beings.  Legends of a single Tenno defending a population show up in several places in the game.  Meanwhile, the Grineer and Orokin hate(d) them. Also, by you can acquire the warframes Inaros and Harrow, among others, which are relics of others who regarded a legend (by Baro Ki'Teer's colony) and a god (by the Red Veil) respectively.

When I awoke, I took full control and grew stronger so that I might protect the world from coming threats.

> "Awakening" refers to a Tenno learning of their true self, and comes with additional powers and abilities.  These additional powers are most useful vs a new faction that shows up halfway through the game.  A "coming threat."

Who I was created to protect I destroyed. I fight to hold the world in balance.

> The Tenno destroyed their creators, the Orokin.  The Tenno also routinely redirect their efforts to fighting different factions to keep them "balanced"

My body is a mask, I can change or shed it as I choose.

> A Tenno can switch between any acquired Warframes at will

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> The *Dragonborn*?

My true identity was hidden from myself and the world, I am not what I appear.

> No one knew you were the Dragonborn until the incident with Alduin

I'm a master of all weapons and fighting styles, I can adapt to any situation.

> Can be an assassin, thief, mage or warrior.

Some worship me, others hate me. I allow legends, myths, and gods to live on.

> Some worship the Dragonborn and others hate him. I allow Daedric princes to live on (Gods) and choose between letting which legend lives on (Civil War storyline,etc.)

When I awoke, I took full control and grew stronger so that I might protect the world from coming threats.

> Dragonborns come every few years only when the dragons rise

Comment: How do they allow legends, myths, and gods to live on? also most times, the they are limited to one or two fighting styles based on the amount of skill points they have

Answer (score 2):

Another possible answer:

> Link, especially from Breath of the Wild

My true identity was hidden from myself and the world, I am not what I appear.

> Link seemed to be a normal hylian, until it is revealed that he is actually the bearer of the triforce of courage and an incarnation of the chosen hero of legend.

I'm a master of all weapons and fighting styles, I can adapt to any situation.

> Link is shown to be a very capable knight/fighter, capable of using various tools at his disposal. BotW amplifies this as he is able to use a various types of weapons incredibly proficiently.

Some worship me, others hate me. I allow legends, myths, and gods to live on.

> As a hero of legend, many would've known of him and perhaps even worship him. Link's deed has saved worlds, allowing their stories to live on. He has also allowed legends/gods to 'live on' in a more direct manner, like saving a dragon spirit in BotW

When I awoke, I took full control and grew stronger so that I might protect the world from coming threats.

> Many LoZ games revolve around link discovering his destiny ('awakening', taken especially literally in BotW) and then following his journey throughout the land, getting stronger before eventually confronting the big bad.

Who am I?

> Link!

Comment: Does anyone actually hate link though? also as far as i know doesnt link awaken when a threat already exists?

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> The frog from **Frogger**?[image]

My true identity was hidden from myself and the world, I am not what I appear.

> Was a tadpole from birth (as the legends tell).

I'm a master of all weapons and fighting styles, I can adapt to any situation.

> Surprisingly agile, can jump in **four (4) different directions!!!**

Some worship me, others hate me. I allow legends, myths, and gods to live on.

> Some [love Frogger](https://www.redbubble.com/people/idaspark/works/15842387-frogger?grid_pos=1&p=t-shirt&rbs=bc169315-5039-472a-8cd8-8481e314abf7&ref=shop_grid&style=mens), some [hate Frogger](http://www.classicgaming.cc/classics/frogger/images/icons/icon-frogger-game-over-512x512.png)!

When I awoke, I took full control and grew stronger so that I might protect the world from coming threats.

> Threats of Cars, Buses, etc.

Comment: they dont use any weapons though? or allow legends, myths, and gods to live on. how do they get stronger?

Answer (score 1):

As Sam Harrington suggested:

You are:

> The avatar

My true identity was hidden from myself and the world, I am not what I appear.

> The avatar doesn't get to know he/she is the avatar up until the age of 12(?) and the world has to find out too

I'm a master of all weapons and fighting styles, I can adapt to any situation.

> The avatar is master of all 4 elements

Some worship me, others hate me.

> Some love the avatar, while other detest the avatar.

I allow legends, myths, and gods to live on.

> The avatar can summon previous avatars for council, who are legends, some are myths and some are looked up to as some kind of god (look at kyoshi and the kyoshi warriors)

When I awoke, I took full control and grew stronger so that I might protect the world from coming threats.

> When the last airbender awoke from the ice, he learned all 4 elements and mastered them, after which he defeated the fire lord (actually the phoenix king in the end)

Comment: The question is tagged video-games though. While AtLA does have its fair share of game adaptations, i think OP might've intended for a character from a primarily video game franchise as the answer

Comment: Well, I agree with you, but on the other hand as you say yourself, AtLA has some games (just like the korra series), therefore this could be a valid/the answer :)

Comment: interesting, but they dont really use any weapons. sure they use elements to fight and can adapt by using different elements, but they arent really a master of all weapons

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Mokujin?

My true identity was hidden from myself and the world, I am not what I appear.

> He was originally a training dummy, that came to life

I'm a master of all weapons and fighting styles, I can adapt to any situation.

> As a mimic character, he uses all of the other character's fighting styles

Some worship me, others hate me. I allow legends, myths, and gods to live on.

> The spirits of mokujin inhabited temples of worship, and, as he arises to fight mythological evils, those evils probably hate him.

When I awoke, I took full control and grew stronger so that I might protect the world from coming threats.

> Mokujin is said to appear only as the world's last resort against evil.

Comment: you only seem to address the first part of point 3. how does it fit the second half?

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Noctis from Final Fantasy XV?

My true identity was hidden from myself and the world, I am not what I appear.

> Not informed he was destined to be the King to defeat the Starscourge until midway through the game.

I'm a master of all weapons and fighting styles, I can adapt to any situation.

> Noctis can use any weapon in the game, as opposed to the other three party members.

Some worship me, others hate me.

> His subjects love him, while Ardyn deeply resents the entire Lucian royal line in general, and Noctis in particular as the culmination of that line.

I allow legends, myths, and gods to live on.

> He doesn't fight and defeat at least Ramuh and Bahamut.

When I awoke, I took full control and grew stronger so that I might protect the world from coming threats.

> After the ten years in the Crystal, he forms a pact with the past kings of Lucis to gain his maximum power to face Ardyn.

Who I was created to protect I destroyed.

> The kings of Lucis originally had protecting the Crystal as part of their duties, but Noctis absorbs all the power out of the Crystal.

I fight to hold the world in balance.

> Fights to defeat the increasing darkness giving power to daemons and increased by them in turn, and restore the balance between day and night.

Comment: the worship/hate is literal from canon lore

Comment: OK, edited that part to mention in-game reasons for different people to love or hate him.  (Though admittedly, lots of characters from just about any work of art could have similar things.)

Comment: is the crystal a person or group of people? also how is he not what he appears?

Comment: OK, I admit some parts of this might have been a bit of a stretch.  I was also thinking of some others from the series like Tidus from X, Zidane from IX, Cloud from VII, Terra from VI, Cecil from IV, who are in various ways "not what they appear" in a way initially hidden from them, though in those cases, saying what they destroy is what they were "created to protect" is more of a stretch, and moreover none of those characters can use every weapon in their respective games.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Darth Revan?

My true identity was hidden from myself and the world, I am not what I appear.

> After Darth Revan was captured, he was hidden from the world, and doesn't appear as Darth Revan at the start of the game.

I'm a master of all weapons and fighting styles, I can adapt to any situation.

> Darth Revan can use all weapons and all force powers in the Kotor games.

Some worship me, others hate me. I allow legends, myths, and gods to live on.

> The Sith worshipped him, the Republic hated him. On his quest, he saved many legends, myths and gods.

When I awoke, I took full control and grew stronger so that I might protect the world from coming threats.

> When it was revealed he was Darth Revan, Revan unlocked additional power.

Who I was created to protect I destroyed. I fight to hold the world in balance.

> Revan ended up destroying the Star Forge and then venturing out in the unknown regions to fight another threat.

Comment: Was the star forge a person or group of people, and was your character created?